# Range.End property has a bug?

Tags: excel, vba

Type some value in column H rows 1 and 2 (can be any column, using H for the purpose of the example). Leave the rest of the column blank.

```
MsgBox (Range("H:H").End(xlDown).Row)
```

produces "2" as expected

Clear the cell in row 2, keeping only a value in row 1.

Now,

```
MsgBox (Range("H:H").End(xlDown).Row)
```

produces "1048576" !!!!!!!!!!!  Shouldn't it produce "1" ?

Thanks.

Comment: start at the bottom and go up: `MsgBox Range("H"& Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: As to why the big number.  do it manually.  Put a value only in H1.  Click on that cell.  Then hit Ctrl-DownArrow.  You will see it goes to the bottom of the sheet.

Comment: Thanks for all the help I received, my problem is solved.(Is this the way to thank someone who has helped you on Stack Overflow?)